# What is difference between below 2 lines?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to add code in cellForRowAt indexPath method like below

```
cell.itemNameLabel.text = nameArray[indexPath.row]
```

but it is showing error as `Cannot assign value of type 'Any' to type 'String?'`

so it can be solved by below 2 ways,

```
cell.fruitName.text = fruitArray[indexPath.row] as? String
```

or

```
cell.fruitName.text = (fruitArray[indexPath.row] as! String)
```

so, my question is what is the difference between 2 answers?

Comment: you can unwrap the optional value like: if let name = fruitArray[indexPath.row] as? String { cell.fruitName.text  = name   }

Answer (score 1):

```
cell.fruitName.text = fruitArray[indexPath.row] as? String
```

Above return type is optional value. means it will be `nil` value return if array is not consist string value.

```
cell.fruitName.text = (fruitArray[indexPath.row] as! String)
```

Above return type is non-optional value. means it will be fire **fatal error** if array is not consist string value.

Comment: Yes. I update it my answer

Answer (score 0):

Below is the generic information for all optionals. Please find it.

When you are using `!` and the *fruitArray[indexPath.row]* is `nil` it will trigger run time error but if use `?` it will fail gracefully.

You can find more detail information in [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID245)

Comment: so cell.fruitName.text = (fruitArray[indexPath.row] as! String) is better way to use it?

Comment: @NikitaPatil No, force wrapping means it will crash if it is `nil`. It's always better to check for value before unwrapping.

Comment: I told already that if it is non nil, better solution check with if let before using it

Comment: The OP is not using `!`, they're using `as!`. That's a force cast, which is a little different than a force unwrap. `let x = "x" as! Int` will crash because "x" can't be cast to an Int.